# How to open all files like pdf,images..etc in jsp page or in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am developing one jsp page in that jsp page i have so many files(pdf,images..) now i want to open that files in jsp page only.

Now I can open only pdf files in jsp but i would like to open all type of files in jsp page

```
 <object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
      Alternative text - include a link <a href="myfile.pdf">to the PDF!</a>
    </object>
```

Any body please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for ?
If yes, you could use Servlet :)

```
@WebServlet("/myfile.pdf.pdf")
public class PdfServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
File file = new File("C:\\User\\myfile.pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Type",    getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"myfile.pdf\"");
     Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
}
}
```

JSP

```
<object data="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myfile.pdf.pdf" 
type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myfile.pdf.pdf">Download PDF</a> </object>
```